# Why I don't see any file or subfolder in folder: Temporary ASP.NET Files after compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a file *FirstPage.aspx*, then debug, but I ***can't see anything generated automatically in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder***:

Why I don't see any file or subfolder in folder: Temporary ASP.NET Files after compilation

Please tell me why?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"ewsdf>
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load()
    {
        lblServerTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>First Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Welcome to ASP.NET 4.0! The current date and time is:
            <asp:Label
                ID="lblServerTime"
                runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: have you searched in the non-64 bit folders ?

Comment: Explain your actual problem. Why does the file need to be there?

Comment: @CodeCaster some files dependencies / small `.compiled` extension file are there when you compile http://i.stack.imgur.com/2fqL3.png

Comment: I follow instructions in one book, and try to find a file like:

public partial class FirstPageCodeBehind
{
protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;
protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label1;
... additional code ...
}
public class firstpagecodebehind_aspx : FirstPageCodeBehind
{
... additional code ...
}

Comment: @CodeCaster I try to find file from the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder after enabling debugging for the application.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I have been saw files and folder in  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

Comment: I try to find file like this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/BRColBX.png?1
and
http://i.imgur.com/hHRqGei.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just can see this folder at: **C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e9c94091\d023916f**
but if you are using a different operating system or ASP.NET configuration, your files may be stored elsewhere (...\root\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx)